# HttpResponseCache 'PUT' request method are not getting cached

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am using [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for server request and [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) for cache response.But response is not cached for PUT requests,did anybody knows what is the reason?Is caching is only for POST and GET methods?

Answer (score 1):

Comment from the source code of HttpResponseCache indicates caching of non GET's is not implemented:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616012dc0d56c2da9af2b9b1183e76c7e044/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java

```
    /*
     * Don't cache non-GET responses. We're technically allowed to cache
     * HEAD requests and some POST requests, but the complexity of doing
     * so is high and the benefit is low.
     */
   return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Some HTTP methods MUST cause a cache to invalidate an entity. This is either the entity referred to by the Request-URI, or by the Location or Content-Location headers (if present). These methods are:
>
> - PUT
> - DELETE
> - POST

(http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)